# Any easy way to notify user to update powerpoint add-in

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, powerpoint

is there a way to notify user about a new version of plugin available?

This can be certainly done by writing some custom code to ping webservice, finding status and based on that displaying message, but then i am wondering if there is a predefined way/template available which can be used and achieved.

If you are sharing sample code, I like C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the best ways to achieve this without writing your own custom code is to use [ClickOnce](http://www.ucertify.com/article/clickonce-technology.html) (or a ClickOnce alternative) - "ClickOnce applications can be self-updating; they can check for newer versions as they become available and automatically replace any updated files."

ClickOnce can be and is often used in conjunction with Office addins - for example, see http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/07/11/how-do-i-programmatically-find-the-deployed-files-for-a-vsto-add-in/

Also, another question regarding open-source options to Click-Once might be a good idea - [clickonce - what is a good open source alternative to clickonce? (DDay.Update)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383612/clickonce-what-is-a-good-open-source-alternative-to-clickonce-dday-update)

Comment: I havent tested this out, but i guess its a good pointer. Will add more comments if i have issues.